# Redirecting many folders and many parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Need the redirection I will try to explain with an example:

Entered address in the browser url bar:

`http://example.com/any/folders/qty/FileName/?any number of key-value pairs separated by &`

to be redirected to the following url:

`http://example.com/any/folders/qty/FileName/FileName.php?any number of key-value pairs separated by &`

Googled for a suitable solution and searched SO but couldn't find anything similar that had a working answer, maybe because most of the questions are pretty confusing. I hope this one is clear enough.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I really don't think that's what you want. I think it is the other way around because it makes no sense the entered URI, the one shown in the browser address bar, be the "ugly" one and the resource address be the "pretty" one.

Comment: I think you are absolutely right, Felipe. Thanks. I will modify my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^.*/([^/]*)/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$    $1%1.php? [L]
```

Will map this:

`http://example.com/any/folders/qty/FileName/?key1=var1&key2=var2&key3=var3`

to this as the resource address:

`http://example.com/any/folders/qty/FileName/FileName.php?key1=var1&key2=var2&key3=var3`

Comment: ¿Where are you testing it? If it is in a local server, for example, modify the `RewriteBase /` with your `site_name`, like this `RewriteBase /site_name`. In short, set the folder where htaccess file is located.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Say your url is:

```
 url=http://www.example.com/page/view?id=10&name=about_us
```

in `index.php`

```
 $req=$_REQUEST['url'];
 $reqExtracted=explode('/',$req);
 $folder=$reqExtracted[0];
 $pagename=$reqExtracted[1];

 $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
 $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
```